# Add active to the current class using only {{action}}

Tags: ember.js

Hi have some items that fires an action, and this action changes some property of the model, and de model fetches again with new params automatically.

I would like to add the 'active' to the current class "list-group-item", but I'm not using {{#link-to}}, just a plain {{action...}}

Is this not possible with just the {{action...}} ?

Thanks,

### code:

```
<div class="list-group">
{{#each issues_types as |issueType|}}
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" {{action "setIssueType" issueType.id}}>
    {{issueType.name}}
 <span class="badge">issueType.count</span>
</a>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `setIssueType` action is called, you can set an `active` boolean property on that particular element.

Our first option is to add that property to the model itself (not so elegant because we are adding a UI-related property to a data object). Anyway, it would look like this:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item {{if issueType.active 'active' ''}}" {{action "setIssueType" issueType.id}}>
```

A better option would be enclosing that link in a Component:

```
{{!-- app/templates/components/issue-type.hbs }}
<a href="#" class="list-group-item {{if active 'active' ''}}" {{action "setIssueType" model.id}}>
    {{model.name}}
 <span class="badge">model.count</span>
</a>
```

along with its Javascript counterpart:

```
// app/components/issue-type.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    setIssueType: function(issueType) {
      // since components don't bubble up actions, send it up here
      this.send('setIssueType', issueType);
    }
  }
});
```

The `active` property would live in the Component. Models (issueType) have a 1:1 relationship with components, so the `active` state would be particular to one model.

In your main template:

```
<div class="list-group">
{{#each issues_types as |issueType|}}
  {{issue-type model=issueType setIssueType='setIssueType' }}
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that will do the trick, but in my case, the action 'setIssueType ' also refresh the area where are the links and the 'active' value is lost, time to refactor some code ;-)

Comment: This is not working, after assigning the 'active' property to true in the action, ALL lines get the 'active' class added, all of them :-(

Comment: Updated code. I haven't tested this code, hope this helps! Let me know what works. Perhaps we need another adjustment

Comment: Thanks, but know I'm getting an 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded', I see that is calling itself in an infinite loop ... The component pass the action to controller? Because I've added a console.log before the 'this.send('setIssueType'),xxx in the component and fires continuously, more than 3000 times ... but the action in the controller never fires (well, I can't see the console.log there) thanks

Comment: I think I made a mistake with `this.send`... could you try `this.sendAction` in the component?

Comment: now I'm not having the infinite-loop, but the active class is not added, I'll have another deep look to the code before 'wasting' more your time ;-) thanks,

Comment: Maybe the component guides at http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/components/ can send you in the right direction. Also try the first option: adding `active` to the model... Good luck!

Comment: I've moved the 'active' property to the component, and now when I click the 'active' is added to the class, the new data is fetched correctly, but when I click to another row, the new one gets 'active' too but the row before also remains 'active'. Also, when I click and make a row active, a queryParams is added, if the user stores this url, I want that line selected, time to rethink ... thanks again for your help!